# Order y-axis on ggforce::geom_parallel_sets

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

Using the dev version of the ggforce package, I can create a Sankey diagram as follows (from the documentation)

```
data <- reshape2::melt(Titanic)
data <- gather_set_data(data, 1:4)

ggplot(data, aes(x, id = id, split = y, value = value)) +
  geom_parallel_sets(aes(fill = Sex), alpha = 0.3, axis.width = 0.1) +
  geom_parallel_sets_axes(axis.width = 0.1) +
  geom_parallel_sets_labels(colour = 'white')
```

[image]

What I'm struggling with, is getting the y-axis variables ordered in any way other than the default, which appears to be reverse alphabetical. For example, changing the plot so `Adult` appeared near the top of the plot, with `Child` below.

I've tried re-leveling the factors before applying `gather_set_data`, as well as re-leveling the `y` variable after applying `gather_set_data`, and neither appear to work. I've also tried defining them as characters and sorting in different orders but that also doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any chance you found a solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't. But this was a while ago and I know development has resumed so maybe this will be fixed soon (last commit I see was 23 hours ago as of this writing).

Comment: Related [GitHub issue by @ssp3nc3r](https://github.com/thomasp85/ggforce/issues/136)

Comment: In my limited use case with only two labels on the *x* that have the same *y* categories, I managed to get it done using `ggplot(data, aes(x, id = id, split = factor(y, levels = c('A', 'B')) ...`.  @ssp3nc3r

Answer (score 3):

Unsure what you would do with `ggforce` as I don't use this package. I assumed the solution would be to re-level the factors as you mentioned but this doesn't seem to be working for you. However, this does work with [`ggalluvial`](http://corybrunson.github.io/ggalluvial/). Furthermore, there is an argument `reverse` that allows you to reverse the order (alphabetical/reverse alphabetical). See below:

#### Default ordering

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalluvial)

df <- as.data.frame(Titanic)

ggplot(as.data.frame(df),
       aes(weight = Freq,
           axis1 = Survived, axis2 = Sex, axis3 = Class)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Class),
                width = 0, knot.pos = 1/4, reverse = FALSE) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/8, reverse = FALSE) +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", label.strata = TRUE, reverse = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = c("Survived", "Sex", "Class")) +
  ggtitle("Titanic survival by class and sex")
```

[image]

#### Reverse ordering

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(df),
       aes(weight = Freq,
           axis1 = Survived, axis2 = Sex, axis3 = Class)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Class),
                width = 0, knot.pos = 1/4, reverse = TRUE) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/8, reverse = TRUE) +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", label.strata = TRUE, reverse = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = c("Survived", "Sex", "Class")) +
  ggtitle("Titanic survival by class and sex")
```

[image]

#### Re-leveling factor

```
df$Class <- factor(df$Class, levels = c("3rd", "1st", "Crew", "2nd"))

ggplot(as.data.frame(df),
       aes(weight = Freq,
           axis1 = Survived, axis2 = Sex, axis3 = Class)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Class),
                width = 0, knot.pos = 1/4, reverse = FALSE) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/8, reverse = FALSE) +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", label.strata = TRUE, reverse = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = c("Survived", "Sex", "Class")) +
  ggtitle("Titanic survival by class and sex")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's a nice solution. I'll try it out and see if I can make it work. I was hoping for for a ggforce solution since that's what I'm using already, but this may work too.

Comment: Hmm... so occasionally the flow doesn't seem to match directly with the stratum - for example, the pink/orange line from female to first class in the first figure overlaps with 2nd class a bit when connecting to the class stratum. This matters a lot in my actual application because small lines look to be coming from the wrong category. Any way to fix that?

Comment: Hm, try adjusting the `width` in `geom_alluvium` to `width = 0.1`. This seems to reduce the overlap.

Comment: It would be nice if we could add spaces in-between the strata but it seems that `ggalluvial` is not designed to do this. ["No gaps are inserted between the strata, so the total height of the diagram reflects the cumulative weight of the observations."](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html). Might be a feature at a later time? ["The option should be available to impose spacing between the strata within each axis."](https://libraries.io/github/corybrunson/ggalluvial) I'm heading to work but I will try an figure something out when I get back.

Answer (score 2):

How about changing y variable into factor as follows?

```
    titanic <- reshape2::melt(Titanic)
    titanic <- gather_set_data(titanic, 1:4)
    titanic$y <- factor(titanic$y, levels=c("Adult", "Child", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "Crew", "Male", "Female", "Yes", "No"))
    ggplot(titanic, aes(x, id = id, split = y, value = value)) +
        geom_parallel_sets(aes(fill = Sex), alpha = 0.3, axis.width = 0.1) +
        geom_parallel_sets_axes(axis.width = 0.1) +
        geom_parallel_sets_labels(colour = 'white')
```