# Re-ordering y-axis of Sankey diagram using ggplot (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, sankey-diagram

I have three nodes in my data that create the attached sankey diagram. I've redacted the labels for each node. The order on the y-axis is alphabetical. That creates a few "sweeps" that cross over (I've highlighted yellow).

Can I define the order for each node along the y-axis? I want to improve the diagram by eliminating the overlapping sweeps. Here's the code I'm using to create the plot.

```
ggplot(dfs2, 
       aes(x = x
           , id = id
           , split = y
           , value = 1
           , node=)) +
  geom_parallel_sets(aes(fill = factor(VST)), alpha = 0.5, 
                     axis.width = aw, sep = sp) +
  geom_parallel_sets_axes(axis.width = aw, sep = sp) +
  geom_parallel_sets_labels(colour = "black", 
                            angle = 0, size = 3.5,
                            axis.width = aw, sep = sp) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank()
        , axis.text.y = element_blank()
        , axis.text.x = element_blank()
        , axis.ticks = element_blank()
        , panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[Sankey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ2wc.png)

I've looked into factors but do not have a full grasp for that concept yet. Expecting to specify the order manually.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  I imagine you're on the right track with a factor - you can supply an ordered set of levels to your factor which is essentially specifying the order manually as you say.  Check the discussions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761815/order-y-axis-on-ggforcegeom-parallel-sets

Answer (score 0):

what you should do is first create a vector of custom order for the three nodes such as:

```
myOrder <- c("Node 1", "Node 2", "Node 3") # you should replace the names Node 1 or 2 or 3 with actual node names
```

and then, convert the variable 'split' into a factor using the vector 'myOrder'.

```
dfs2$split <- factor(dfs2$split, levels = myOrder)
```

Then change the code, using the factored 'split' variable in your ggplot code:

```
ggplot(dfs2, 
       aes(x = x,
           id = id,
           split = split,
           value = 1,
           node = )) +
  geom_parallel_sets(aes(fill = factor(VST)), alpha = 0.5, axis.width = aw, sep = sp) +
  geom_parallel_sets_axes(axis.width = aw, sep = sp) +
  geom_parallel_sets_labels(colour = "black",  angle = 0, size = 3.5, axis.width = aw, sep = sp) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

Since I do not have the complete code or data from you, just thought of this... please check and revert what you get?